# HTML: Connect to elements from different SVGs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I've got a website with three SVGs in it. Now I want to show connections between elements in the different svgs.

For that I want to draw a simple line from element1 (#element1) in svg1 to element6 in svg2.

Nope, I can't simply create a svg with ALL svgs together to draw a line in an svg-object because I've got different svg1 images (loaded dynmanically) and svg2 images.

So I have to draw on clean html DOM. Is that possible?

Comment: You can place all of your dynamically loaded SVGs inside another SVG. Then you might be able to find their center points and then draw a path between them, i.e. `<svg id="outer"><svg id="inner-1"></svg><svg id="inner-2"></svg></svg>`. You might also be able to take the contents of the dynamically loaded SVGs and place each of their content inside of another SVG as a `<symbol>`, i.e. `<svg id="outer"><symbol id="from-inner-1"></symbol><symbol id="from-inner-2"></symbol><use xlink:href="#from-inner-1"/><use xlink:href="#from-inner-2"/></svg>`.

Answer (score 0):

Like @hungerstar points out, you can easily do that. Except I'd go with embedded image more like this;

> [CodePen to tinker](http://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/dpxGqq)

```css
svg {
  border: red 1px solid;
}
svg line {
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Smiley.svg" />
  <image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Smiley.svg" x="200" y="200"/>
  <line fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="50" y1="50" x2="250" y2="250"/>
</svg>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.